# Limit the files while deploying - git

Tags: linux, git, github, gitlab, bitbucket

I am using Gitlab to deploy my application.

I have few files that needs to be synced to the Gitlab but dont want that to be deployed to the Production.

eg: read.md,notes,snippets.

I know that adding the files to the .gitignore will do the task but it will completely ignore the files.

Are there any other alternative?

Comment: Why do you need an alternative?

Comment: @Christoph yes, coz I am now manually deleting those files :(

Comment: Git is a version control tool, not a deployment tool. Search for deployment tools and you'll find plenty of things that can do what you want. Asking for recommendations like this is off-topic here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a way to tell git not to take changes into account specific files :

```
git update-index --skip-worktree path/to/file
```

([doc](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-update-index#_skip_worktree_bit))

You can set it before deploying to production, and unset it for your everyday exchanges on gitlab.

(The question about the respective interests of using `--skip-worktree` or `--assume-unchanged` has already been answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13630849/git-difference-between-assume-unchanged-and-skip-worktree), you might want to take a look.)